# Ruby run bash commands with different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process

I am writing a Rails application, which runs by say user A. Now there is some other user B, which is authorised to ssh on some other server and run some commands on that server. The code is following:

```
Net::SSH.start(server, username, :password => password) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec("set of commands authorised to B")
end
```

How can I change user to B when performing above task and than again move back to user A. I was checking gem [popen4](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/popen4/0.1.2), but couldn't found if I can start a process with different user.

Comment: I don't quite know what your are really asking here but when you connect via ssh you will be running a shell as whatever user user you used to connect. eg. if i ran `ssh saurabh@example.com` I would logged in as `saurabh` on the remote server (example.com) and not as my local unix user or in the case of rails whichever user owns the web process.

Answer (score 3):

In the UNIX process model you are able to switch between users, but this is only permitted if you're running with `root` level access, something that's generally a bad idea for most processes.

The mechanical process is:

```
Process.uid = uid_of_user_b
```

This employs [`Process.uid=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Process.html#method-c-uid-3D) to effect the change, but it will error out if you're not allowed to do this.

The `sudo` tool is a good alternative. You can do things like:

```
sudo -u user_b command
```

This will depend on `sudo` being set up correctly for your user.